# Sharing Address Table with Two Entities

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have two entities in my database that both require addresses. Customers can have multiple addresses. Restaurants can have one address for each ID. How should I organise the relationships? I currently have the address table referencing the user it belongs to but it can also belong to a restaurant.

**Address:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.address (
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state_province` varchar(128),
  `zip_post` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.user(username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**User:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.user (
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Restaurant:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.restaurant (
  `restaurant_id` int(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.address(address_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 'through' table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (user_address
       address_id int,
       user_name varchar(32), 
      FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.user(username),
      FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.address(address_id),
      PRIMARY KEY (user_id,user_name))
```

Don't need the username in the address table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grabatakeaway.address (
  `address_id` int(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state_province` varchar(128),
  `zip_post` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES grabatakeaway.user(username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

May I also suggest that you have an auto incrementing id field for the users table? That will lead to a smaller index on it, as well as a smaller index on the through table.

Comment: What about for restaurant? Same thing?

Comment: yes, same thing. This creates a many to many relationship and allows restaturents also to have many addresses. If you don't need it, keep the current structure for it.

Comment: Great, thanks! I will go ahead and implement this. If all is good I will mark this as answered, cheers!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do let me know if you run into any difficulties

Comment: so how did it go?

Comment: sorry forgot to get back! worked perfectly just took me a while to implement to a point I had forgotten about this post

Comment: No worries. Glad to have helped